# What's the difference between a[] and a[:] when assigning values?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, slice

I happen to see this snippet of code:

```
a = []  
a = [a, a, None]
# makes a = [ [], [], None] when print

a = []
a[:] = [a, a, None]
# makes a = [ [...], [...], None] when print
```

It seems the `a[:]` assignment assigns a pointer but I can't find documents about that. So anyone could give me an explicit explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, `a` is a name - it points to an object, in this case, a list.

In your first example, `a` initially points to the empty list, then to a new list.

In your second example, `a` points to an empty list, then it is *updated* to contain the values from the new list. This does not change the list `a` references.

The difference in the end result is that, as the right hand side of an operation is evaluated first, in both cases, `a` points to the original list. This means that in the first case, it points to the list that used to be `a`, while in the second case, it points to itself, making a recursive structure.

If you are having trouble understanding this, I recommend taking a look at [it visualized](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+%5B%5D++%0Aa+%3D+%5Ba,+a,+None%5D%0A%0Aa+%3D+%5B%5D%0Aa%5B%3A%5D+%3D+%5Ba,+a,+None%5D&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&py=2&curInstr=0).

Comment: The online tutor step 3 shows that the second empty list in `a` is actually a pointer to the first one. Could you also explain that?

Comment: @can. They are both the same list. When you put `a` twice in the list, the same object is referenced twice from that list. You need to copy the list if you want it to be a new one with the same elements.

Comment: Then how can I make a copy in this case?

Comment: @can. [`copy.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) (or [`copy.deepcopy()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) if you have nested data structures).

Comment: `new_l = old_l[:]` will also work (not deep, though) as a replacement for importing `copy.copy()`.

Comment: @pythonm I would recommend `new_l = list(old_l)` as a more readable alternative than the list slice if you are not going to use `copy.copy()`.

Answer (score 7):

The first will point `a` to a new object, the second will mutate `a`, so the list referenced by `a` is still the same.

For example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
print b # [1, 2, 3]

a[:] = [3, 2, 1]
print b # [3, 2, 1]
a = [1, 2, 3]
#b still references to the old list
print b # [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

More clear example from @pythonm response

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=a
>>> c=a[:]
>>> a.pop()
4
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> c
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```